# Deserializing SFDC REST services JSON response

Tags: c#, json, rest, salesforce, servicestack

Receiving following response from SFDC REST Web Service (string **jsonResponse** below):

```
{
    "responseDataList": [{
        "salesforceRecordId": "a00C000000L5DQRIA3",
        "recordName": "Computer_Name_2",
        "IsSuccess": true,
        "errorMessage": null
    }]
}
```

Trying to deserialize it with ServiceStack.JsonSerializer:

```
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string jsonResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    ResponseDataList list = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<ResponseDataList>(jsonResponse);
```

ResponseDataList has following structure:

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public string salesforceRecordId { get; set; }
    public string recordName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseDataList 
{
    List<ResponseData> responseDataList { get; set; }
}
```

However after deserialization ResponseDataList list is null. What do I do wrong, how to deserialize correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By making responseDataList public, I was able to deserialize properly.

```
public class ResponseDataList 
{
    public List<ResponseData> responseDataList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Child misspell, thanks. However I got error here: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'ResponseDataList', got string starting with: "{\"responseDataList\":[{\"salesforceRecordId\":\". What is wrong here?

Comment: Hmmm... seems response contains explicit double quotes, escape characters, etc. Strange, how to overcome this?

Comment: If the server is returning an escaped string, use the serializer to unescape it      JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<string>(jsonResponse);

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using Json.NET to do the deserialization instead of Service Stack, you can easily do it as follows without having to make the `DataResponseList` class:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var json = client.DownloadString("url");
IList<ResponseData> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseData>>(json);
```

Comment: Which .Net component contains this? WCF?

Comment: It's a third-party library like service stack available as a NuGet package, but it's use has become so widespread, Visual Studio automatically includes and references it in MVC 4 projects. You can search NuGet for Json.NET, or here is the website: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx